# Google map v3 infobox close event

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have one map and one marker on it. When i go with my mouse over the marker an infobox appears. What I want to do is that when I leave with my mouse (mouseout) the infobox to disapear, but only in case the mouse didn't go over the infobox. If the mouse went over the infobox I want the infobox to remain visible until I move my mouse of of the infobox.

So, as long as my mouse stays either on the marker or on the infobox, it should be visible, and when I leave them the infobox must disapear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru21/VvMr3/ If you mouseover the marker, the infobox will apear. After that i want to move on the infobox because i want to put some buttons there. When i leave the infobox it must disapear instantly like it does now when i move the mouse out of the marker. I hope now its more clear..

Comment: Thank you my friend for the response !

Comment: Have you noticed that when you go with the mouse over the marker and after that over the infobox and after that back on the marker, the infobox disapeares? ..witch is not normal.

Comment: @paulinho: yes. remove `setTimeout` from the `ib` event handler (`domready`) and it works as it should. i updated the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/VvMr3/14/

Comment: When you moveback to the marker, the infobox is flashing and it should not. I already tested this case..

Comment: @paulinho: it flashes because you are leaving the infobox to enter the marker (so its closes the infobox, and then reopens it). to stop the flash you must prevent it from closing when moving from `ib` to the marker.

Comment: It works, i dont know what other modifications i've done but it seem to work now. It's a mistery..thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

very simple, actually.

- attach a mouse event handler to your `marker`
- attach a `domready` event handler to your `infowindow`
- create a `div` inside your `infowindow` and attach a mouse event handler to it

what i did:

- added a timer to close the `infowindow` after a few seconds unless there is a mouse over it

some code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    infowindow.open(map, marker)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    t = setTimeout(function () {
        infowindow.close()
    }, 3000);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function () {
    $('#infodiv').on('mouseenter', function () {
        clearTimeout(t);
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            infowindow.close()
        }, 1000);
    })
});
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/vA4eQ/

Comment: @paulinho: saying you are not a programmer is an insult? should i be mad if someone says i am not a mechanic? if you really believe what i said is offensive, feel free to flag my post as such, so the moderators can resolve the issue. by the way, i'm not a mechanic, but i am a programmer, so i don't need to copy-paste. and SO is not a coder-for-hire place. we give hints, tips, put you in the right direction. you should've used your 3 days membership to read the [faq].